# SQLCMD.EXE его расположение в \\Program Files для разных версий Windows

Tags: sql, sql-server, inno-setup

Создаю в InnoSetup инсталляционный пакет, БД, SQL сервер 2016 Express, в файле SQLCMD.EXE прописываются параметры по созданию БД MSSQL из *.back файла:

```
 Filename: "{pf64}\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd.exe"; Description: "Удаление текущей базы если существует она"; Parameters: "-U sa -P 123123 -S DESKTOP-1H3LSFS\JKOM -d master -Q ""IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SYS.DATABASES WHERE NAME='ecad_jk') DROP DATABASE ecad_jk;;"" "; StatusMsg: "Развертывание базы winDraw..."; Components: srv
Filename: "{pf64}\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd.exe"; Description: "Развертывание базы"; Parameters: "-U sa -P 123123 -S DESKTOP-1H3LSFS\JKOM -d master -Q ""RESTORE DATABASE ecad_jk FROM DISK='{app}\Base\dealer.bak' WITH MOVE 'ecad' TO '{app}\Base\ecad.mdf', MOVE 'ecad_log' TO '{app}\Base\ecad_log.ldf', REPLACE;;"" "; StatusMsg: "Удаление текущей базы..."; Components: srv
```

Как видите, каталог с расположением SQLCMD.EXE задан хардкорно, только для версии Windows 8.1. Интересует в каком каталоге //Program Files для SQL сервера будет расположен данный файл - минимум. Максимум хотелось бы узнать как средствами InnoSetup можно проверять установленную Windows версию. Спасибо

Comment: По второму вопросу: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_getwindowsversionex

Comment: Спасибо Вам за инфу

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/file-locations-for-default-and-named-instances-of-sql-server

Comment: SQL Server добавляет в %PATH% пути к своим папкам с утилитами. Нет необходимости прописывать полный путь, просто sqlcmd работает.

Answer (score -1):

В скриптах на все случаи жизни для определения разных версий разной разрядности

```
[Code]
function IsWin2k: Boolean;
var
ver: TWindowsVersion;
begin
GetWindowsVersionEx(ver);
Result := UsingWinNT and (ver.Major >= 5) and Not IsWin64;
end;

function IsWinXP: Boolean;
var
ver: TWindowsVersion;
begin
GetWindowsVersionEx(ver);
Result := UsingWinNT and (ver.Major < 6) and Not IsWin64;
end;

function IsWinXP64: Boolean;
var
ver: TWindowsVersion;
begin
GetWindowsVersionEx(ver);
Result := UsingWinNT and (ver.Major < 6) and IsWin64;
end;

function IsVista: Boolean;
var
ver: TWindowsVersion;
begin
GetWindowsVersionEx(ver);
Result := UsingWinNT and (ver.Major = 6) and (ver.Minor >= 0) and Not IsWin64;
end;

function IsVista64: Boolean;
var
ver: TWindowsVersion;
begin
GetWindowsVersionEx(ver);
Result := UsingWinNT and (ver.Major = 6) and (ver.Minor >= 0) and IsWin64;
end;

function IsWin7: Boolean;
var
ver: TWindowsVersion;
begin
GetWindowsVersionEx(ver);
Result := UsingWinNT and (ver.Major = 6) and (ver.Minor >= 1) and Not IsWin64;
end;

function IsWin764: Boolean;
var
ver: TWindowsVersion;
begin
GetWindowsVersionEx(ver);
Result := UsingWinNT and (ver.Major = 6) and (ver.Minor >= 1) and IsWin64;
end;

function IsWin8: Boolean;

var
ver: TWindowsVersion;
begin
GetWindowsVersionEx(ver);
Result := UsingWinNT and (ver.Major = 6) and (ver.Minor >= 2) and Not IsWin64;
end;

function IsWin864: Boolean;

var
ver: TWindowsVersion;
begin
GetWindowsVersionEx(ver);
Result := UsingWinNT and (ver.Major = 6) and (ver.Minor >= 2) and IsWin64;
end;

function IsWin81: Boolean;

var
ver: TWindowsVersion;
begin
GetWindowsVersionEx(ver);
Result := UsingWinNT and (ver.Major = 6) and (ver.Minor >= 3) and Not IsWin64;
end;

function IsWin8164: Boolean;

var
ver: TWindowsVersion;
begin
GetWindowsVersionEx(ver);
Result := UsingWinNT and (ver.Major = 6) and (ver.Minor >= 3) and IsWin64;
end;

function IsWin10: Boolean;

var
ver: TWindowsVersion;
begin
GetWindowsVersionEx(ver);
Result := UsingWinNT and (ver.Major = 10) and (ver.Minor >= 0) and Not IsWin64;
end;

function IsWin1064: Boolean;

var
ver: TWindowsVersion;
begin
GetWindowsVersionEx(ver);
Result := UsingWinNT and (ver.Major = 10) and (ver.Minor >= 0) and IsWin64;
end;
```

Юзайте

Comment: Ану - ка мил человек объясни, почему отминусовал пожалуйста

Comment: я бы предположил что за то, что в вопросе у вас про путь к SQLCMD, который зависит от инсталляционного пути SQL Server (который может быть вообще любым), а в ответе - не имеющее отношения к вопросу определение версии Windows.

Comment: а по теме - я бы предложил вам читать нужный путь из реестра, из ключа `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\ClientSetup\@ODBCToolsPath`, а не угадывать по версии windows

Comment: Но ведь для разных версий Windows он различый

Comment: это ключ в реестре. он одинаковый для всех версий Windows (т.е. он будет одинаковый на всех машинах с 130-м sql server). Значение ключа - абсолютный путь к Tools на этой конкретной машине, тоже никак от версии Windows не зависит